# Online AES tools unable to decrypt my value

Tags: java, android-studio, encryption, aes

I'm really new to AES_256 encryption so I would like to get some insight and understand what's going on with this situation.

I have created an AESUtil to encrypt some sensitive data that will save into a text file, with my decrypt function, I also able to decrypt the encrypted value. However, when I try to decrypt it with [online tools](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption), it shows error of **"Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption."**

What's going wrong? as my code as it able to decrypt perfectly, but I can't expect my QA to run my code every time to decrypt the value, I believe using online AES tool would be easier for them.

Here's my code

```
public class AESUtil {

    private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String secretKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        keyBytes = sha.digest(keyBytes);
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    }

    public static String encryptData(String secretKey, String content) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = getSecretKeySpec(secretKey);

            // Generate a random IV
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            // Encrypt
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Combine IV and encrypted content
            byte[] combined = new byte[iv.length + encrypted.length];
            System.arraycopy(iv, 0, combined, 0, iv.length);
            System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, combined, iv.length, encrypted.length);

            // Return the combined data as a Base64 encoded string
            return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(combined, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while encrypting", e);
        }
    }

    public static String decryptData(String secretKey, String encryptedContent) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = getSecretKeySpec(secretKey);

            // Decode the Base64 encoded string
            byte[] combined = android.util.Base64.decode(encryptedContent, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

            // Extract the IV and encrypted content
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] encrypted = new byte[combined.length - 16];

            System.arraycopy(combined, 0, iv, 0, 16);
            System.arraycopy(combined, 16, encrypted, 0, encrypted.length);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            // Decrypt
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

            // Convert the decrypted byte array back to a string
            return new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while decrypting", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
String secretKey = "my very secret key 000!!"
```

Comment: High probably IV encoding problem with the site if not the key. Could you output all in hex or base64 then try again? Or at least provide us?

Comment: The linked online tool doesn't appear to perform the hashing of the 'secret key' to the value used to create the key spec. (You don't specify where this string is likely to come from, but if it's more of a 'password' you should be using a KDF to derive a key - rather than a simple hash.)

Comment: Online tools don't work as specifically as you assume: For decryption, in addition to the key derivation mentioned in the previous comment, the tool would have to Base64 decode the data and then separate IV and ciphertext. Most tools are just able to decrypt a ciphertext for a *given* key and IV.

Comment: And even if you perform the individual steps yourself, the tool wouldn't be able to process the key hash and the IV, since no encoding can be specified for either, instead an ASCII or UTF-8 encoding is performed under the hood (which does not work for a key *hash* and a *random* IV).